# placing json value in a list as links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, phonegap-build

i am working on mobile app using phonegap.Here i am trying to display my database values into a list in my html page called **nextpage.html**.But i couldn't insert it as a links. could you pls help me to insert it as a links. when i click on those links it will display the details of that partcular data into a new page.

**nextPage.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/nextPage.js"></script>    
 <title>Edfutura1</title>
 </head>
<center>
<body id="category_id">
<div data-role="page" id="catlist"> 
<div  id="loading" > </div>  
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
 <h1>category</h1>
 </div> 
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <form id="nextForm" > 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="category">

              <li>
              </li>  
            </ul> 


            </form>

        </div>

 </div>                 
 </body>
 </center>
 </html>
```

**nextPage.js**

```
   var base_url="http://dev.edfutura.com/nithin/jps/edfuturaMob/";  
   $(document).on("pageinit","#catlist", function() {


 var submitUrl = base_url+"categorylist/get_categorylist"; 


     //$("#loading").css("display", "block");  


         $.ajax({
        url: submitUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response)
        {

            var categoryList = $('#category');
            var category;
      for(var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++)
      {

       //pls do something
        category = response[i];
        categoryList.append($('<li>').attr('id',  category.category_id).html(category.category_name));


      }

         },
         error: function() 
        {
            alert("error");

        }

    }); 
    });
```

**category_id** and **category_name** are my db values. i want the details of category_name by clicking on it. i failled to do so. pls help me...
**my output is**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the anchor tag inside the li element:

```
var a = $('<a>').attr('href', '#').html(category.category_name);
categoryList.append($('<li>').attr('id',  category.category_id).append(a));
```

Comment: on $('<a>').attr('href', '#'), replace '#' for the link of the next page. If you put www.google.com, it will redirect you to google's site, for instance.

Comment: how can pass or access the href id

Answer (score 0):

replace your append with this:

```
    $('#category').append('<li id="' + category.category_id + '">' + category.category_name + '</li>');
```

not the cleanest solution but will work

Comment: sir its already working for me. but im trying to make it as a links. i dont know how to append these as links